# Pass GCM message to Fragment - Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I'm new to Xamarin and Android. I have an app that receives gcm notifications, so i need this notifications to be passed to a fragment which contains a listview. I want to append these notifications in the listview without reopening the fragment - just like whatsapp chat window. I populate the listview like this :

```
  public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  List<ChatHistory> lstChatHistory = LocalDB.GetChatHistory(db, communityRefNo);

                for (int x = 0; x < lstChatHistory.Count; x++)
                {
                    _mySimpleItemLoader.LoadMoreItems(lstChatHistory[x].TyperName, lstChatHistory[x].message, lstChatHistory[x].dateCreated);
                    ListViewItemsCount++;
                }

                lvChat.Adapter = new ListViewChatAdapter(this.Context, _mySimpleItemLoader);
}
```

The gcm receiver method has the following parameters :

```
public override void OnMessageReceived(string from, Bundle data)
{
    //pass the received info to the listview above without reopening the fragment above
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by adding the following code :

**Gcm Service**

```
Intent intentReply = new Intent("test");  
                        intentReply.PutExtra("reply", message);
                  Android.Support.V4.Content.LocalBroadcastManager.GetInstance(this).SendBroadcast(intentReply);
```

**Receiver in fragment**

```
private static MyApp inst; 

[BroadcastReceiver]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "test" })]  
public class HomeBroadcastReciever : BroadcastReceiver
 {
      public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
      {
          string replyMessage = intent.GetStringExtra("reply");
           inst.UpdateChat(replyMessage);
      }
 }
```

**MyApp : Fragment**

```
public void UpdateChat(string replyMessage)
{
  //update control here
}
```